# how to find the position of an element in the sequence through selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

In the image, I want to find the position of the "ContentHotspot" is six in the div class of "MainLoader"

Is there a way through css selector , xpath etc to find out the position is six.

Rest all are link elements 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
//div[count(//*[contains(@class,'ContentHotspot')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

References:

- [XPath `count()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count)
- [XPath `contains()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains)
- [XPath `preceding-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)